# Price format, change size after decimal

Tags: javascript

I use this code to format price:

```js
$.each($('.price-lbl-cust'), function() {
    var price = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(price.replace(/(\D*)(\d*\,)(\d*)/,
        '<span style="font-size:16px;font-weight:600;">$1</span><span style="font-size: 1.675rem;line-height: 1.5rem;font-weight:600;">$2</span><span style="font-size: .92222em;font-weight:600;">$3</span>'
    ));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-lbl-cust">144,40</div>
```

this give me output:
[image: output]

is correct.

But the issue is when price is example:
2,948,11

then give me output:
[image: output]

only first number 2 is big, and second 948 and third 11 is small.

How to change and add when price have 2 decimal then make small price only after last decimal ?

Comment: Why does your price contain _two_ commas in the first place? Makes rather little sense to speak of "decimals" then to begin with, because there _can_ be only one set of decimals, and only one decimal separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

`/(\d*\,)(\d*\,)*(\d+)/` will make sure to select everything before the last comma.

```js
$.each($('.price-lbl-cust'), function() {
    var price = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(price.replace(/(\d*\,)(\d*\,)*(\d+)/,
        '<span style="font-size: 1.675rem;line-height: 1.5rem;font-weight:600;">$1</span><span style="font-size: 1.675rem;line-height: 1.5rem;font-weight:600;">$2</span><span style="font-size: .92222em;font-weight:600;">$3</span>'
    ));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-lbl-cust">2,948,11</div>
```